# Network routing with an ADSL router and two wifi routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing

Ok so here's my network setup -

```
ADSL Router (non wifi) -> Wireless N Router (with LAN switch as well) -> Desktop
                                        |
                          Wireless G Router (Wireless bridge from the N Router)
```

ADSL Router's network is 192.168.1.0 and at present I have connected the ADSL router to N router's one of the LAN ports instead of the WAN port and another LAN port has my desktop.

The Wireless G Router is set in Access Point mode with an IP of 192.168.1.3/255.255.255.0 and the wireless N router has IP 192.168.1.2/255.255.255.0

Also, the G router is not connected physically, the N router supports wireless bridging, so I'm bridging the routers.

Now the problem is that, I cannot access the outside world network from any wireless device on the G router whereas I'm able to access from the N router. It seems there's no routing table entry present (not sure why does it need that when all it has to do is route the traffic through 192.168.1.1). I get no route to host response from my N router when I ping outside world from the G router. Moreover, the same works if I manually add a routing entry in N router's table say for 8.0.0.0/255.255.255.0 via 192.168.1.1

How do I specify a general routing rule in the table so that for all ips this routing is followed? I tried 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255, but it doesn't work, gives an error.

As to why I need the G router is I'm using it as repeater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be a routing issue at all. The only device on your network that should be acting as a router-like device is your ADSL box, which is acting not just as a router, but as a full NAT gateway. The N AP and the G AP should have NAT, routing, and DHCP **dis**abled. They should just be dumb layer 2 bridging devices. If adding a route entry fixes anything, then either your N AP or your G AP isn't acting as a simple layer 2 device.

Comment: It's the N AP I guess. Because, my G router has a Access Point mode where all other functions are disabled except wireless and LAN ports (the WAN port becomes a LAN one then). Also, the setup seems to work the other way around with the roles of N & G routers swapped. :S

Comment: Moreover, the N router doesn't have an AP mode, so I guess I'm good with both the routers swapped.